# Unwanted space on responsive table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I use "table-responsive" wrapper on my table the horizontal scrollbar does not show up on smaller screens and when I add "display: block !important" to the table, the scrollbar works on small screens but it leaves unwanted space at the right side on large screen, as shown in the image below.

[image: Table]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="main-table" class="table table-bordered" style="display: block !important;>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item No</th>
                    <th style="width:25%">Description</th>
                    <th style="width:10%">PAX</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th style="width:11%">No of Days</th>
                    <th>Amount ZMK</th>
                    <th style="width:6%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="only-numbers" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers pax" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers price" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers non-edit total"></td>
                    <td class="remove-row">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="only-numbers" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers pax" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers price" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers" contenteditable="true"></td>
                    <td class="only-numbers non-edit total"></td>
                    <td class="remove-row">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5">Total</th>
                        <td class="non-edit">
                            <strong id="grand-total">0.00</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="non-edit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _“and when I add "display: block !important" to the table, the scrollbar works on small screens but it leaves unwanted space at the right side on large screen”_ - well then set it for small screens only to begin with …?

Comment: If you use `display: block` on a `table` it will no longer behave like a `table`

Comment: If you remove the `display: block` and fix the missing `"` after `!important` your example works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: removing display: block makes the scrollbar not to show up on smaller screens

Comment: What browser do you use? Because the scrollbar does appear in Chrome and Firefox on Windows. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r7wme3b1/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the " after table style attribute.

```
<table id="main-table" class="table table-bordered" style="display: block !important;">
```